# How does gdb start another program passed to it as input

Tags: gdb

I have read how gdb `attaches` to another running process from this link:

[How does a debugger peek into another process' memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032633/how-does-a-debugger-peek-into-another-process-memory)

But what about starting a program directly with it as such:

```
gdb ./my_program
```

Does gdb `fork` and run `my_program` using it and attach to it like it's explained int he above link (i.e with `ptrace` on linux), or the process is entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or the process is entirely different?

No: the process is the same -- `fork`, parent calls `PTRACE_ATTACH`, child calls `PTRACE_TRACEME`. That last point guarantees that GDB can debug the child process from its first instruction.

There is one additional complication: GDB uses `$SHELL` in order to handle input / output redirection,  so there is `fork` -> `exec shell` (in the child)  -> `exec program`.