# Why can some debuggers modify the memory of other programs

Tags: debugging, memory-management, operating-system

I'm taking courses on operating systems, and the book says that:

> Only if the virtual address is “too big” or negative will the result be a fault, causing an exception to be raised.

I noticed that, in practice, there are some debuggers that can **modify** the memory of other programs.  
Why aren't these debuggers terminated by the OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a debugger peek into another process' memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032633/how-does-a-debugger-peek-into-another-process-memory) - while the question does indicate it is about _reading_ memory, the main answer does note that ptrace can also *write* to the memory of the other process